# How do I read arguments from "read" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

What the title says is my question, how to check and get arguments from "read statement" into $1, $2 etc...

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You use `set` to set the values of the positional parameters.

```
$ read a b <<< "hello world"
$ set -- "$a" "$b"
$ echo "$1"
hello
$ echo "$2"
world
```

Comment: I generally use `set -- arg1 arg2 ...` in case $arg1 starts with a `-` character: `read a b <<< "-x world"`

Comment: Agreed. Ironically, I used it when it really was strictly unnecessary, in an earlier draft where I was hardcoding the values: e.g. `set -- 1 2`. Then when it became a good idea, I omitted them. \*facepalm*